# Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories:

Tags: android, android-studio, antivirus

Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories:

```
 C:\Users\user.name\.AndroidStudio3.5\system
 C:\Users\user.name\Documents\app-new-code  
 C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
 C:\Users\user.name\.gradle
```

Can anyone help me, how to get this disable this setting or increase the performance of android studio? I am using **android studio version 3.5**.

Comment: which antivirus are you using? Also, note that excluding those folder from the antivirus scan could put your computer at risk because someone could store a virus in those directory knowing people might exclude them

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should exclude this dir from antivirus in your machine.

1. Open Windows Defender Security Center.
2. Select Virus & threat protection > Virus & threat protection settings > Add or remove exclusions.
3. Under Add an exclusion, select folder

Comment: I didn't find any **Add or remove exclusions** option in Virus & threat protection .

Comment: @Alfaizkhan click on manage security under Virus & threat protection settings 1st. As I mentioned above, excluding a folder from your protection increases the risk of getting infected. You can exclude a process though from the protection, you might want to check out which option is the best

Answer (score 5):

### Cause

While Android Studio build process is in action, it create a lot of intermediate files in order to compile and package source code and resources. Enabling real time scanning in antivirus softwares will force it to scan all these newly created files for vulnerabilities. This is may interfere with the Android Studio build process, causing builds to run dramatically slower.

### Fix

Exclude real-time scanning on these directories.

**Gradle cache**

`%USERPROFILE%\.gradle`

**Android Studio projects**

`%USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects`

**Android SDK**

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK`

**Android Studio system files**

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\system`

This is how you can accomplish the same in different antivirus softwares.

[Windows Defender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-extension-file-exclusions-windows-defender-antivirus)

[Kaspersky](https://help.kaspersky.com/KESWin/11/en-US/128138.htm)

[AVG Antivirus](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en&urlName=AVG-Antivirus-scan-exclusions&supportType=home)

***Note:*** You can also disable the disable real-time scanning completely. This method isn't recommenced since it will open security risks.